# Wifi keeps dropping frequently Ubuntu 17.10, RT3290 802.11n

Tags: wireless, 17.10, ralink

I use college WiFi and my connection frequently drops while Windows users use WiFi smoothly.

I get this output on running

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

[image: terminal screenshot RT3290]

Comment: When your connection drops, what does running `dmesg` print related to Wifi?

Comment: dmesg prints this when connection goes off [here] https://docs.google.com/document/d/1i8JGjKCxwQLdYLNmxcFaYOGsJc7WzPU8g3WLCjku5uI/edit?usp=sharing @SurvivalMachine

Comment: Have you tried disabling Wifi power management?

Comment: It seems like @SurvivalMachine is right. For me `iw dev <device> get power_save` returned "Power save: on". Then I did `iw dev <device> set power_save off` and the issue seems to be gone. I could not do this with NetworkManager running. Instead I had to do it manually, with NetworkManager stopped.

Comment: Unfortunately the above didn't solve my problem. It still disconnects apparently for no reason. So my next approach was to change wifi encryption, as suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1306364/109449 After a couple hours using a different type of security, it seems like the problem's gone.