# 20.04 can't connect to 5Ghz wifi after update

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

About 2 days ago I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and everything was working great. This morning I ran apt update and apt upgrade and rebooted and now my wifi won't connect to my 5Ghz network. It will connect to my 2.4Ghz network.
This is on a Lenovo ThinkPad T410.

```
$ nmcli device
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION         
enp0s25  ethernet  connected     Wired connection 1 
wlp3s0   wifi      disconnected  --
```

info from lspci:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:2153]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 [8086:4239] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

results of sudo lshw -class network:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 35
       serial: 58:94:6b:d9:ac:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-36-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 6000-4.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:31 memory:f2400000-f2401fff
```

results of lspci:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
```

results of rfkill:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

dmesg output:

```
[ 2287.166207] perf: interrupt took too long (7719 > 7717), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25750
[ 3057.673757] wlp3s0: authenticate with d8:07:b6:b0:ac:be
[ 3057.676517] wlp3s0: send auth to d8:07:b6:b0:ac:be (try 1/3)
[ 3057.751437] wlp3s0: authenticated
[ 3057.753283] wlp3s0: associate with d8:07:b6:b0:ac:be (try 1/3)
[ 3057.754414] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from d8:07:b6:b0:ac:be (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=7)
[ 3057.757489] wlp3s0: associated
[ 3057.853016] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by d8:07:b6:b0:ac:be
[ 3102.648706] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from d8:07:b6:b0:ac:be by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

result of dmesg | grep -i firmware:

```
iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode failed with error -2
```

when I try to connect to the 5Ghz it takes a long time, then the error message shows up:
Activation of network connection failed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it.  I went into my routers wifi setup and changed the security to wpa2/wpa3-personal

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is one more hope for me, as I tried a lot of stuff already and nothing seems to fix this disconnection problem. What I noticed so far was that using Wireless N on my router causes disconnections while using "Legacy" apparently didn't. I also tried disabling power save mode, but it didn't work (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032157/wifi-keeps-dropping-frequently-ubuntu-17-10-rt3290-802-11n#comment1678939_1032157). Now I tried changing the security on router and, at least for a couple hours, it worked. Let's see how it goes...

Comment: you're welcome!  Hope it continues to work for you

Comment: Unfortunately changing the security didn't solve my problem. Apparently randomly, suddenly I cannot ping the gateway anymore, nor any host. I'm disconnected, although NetworkManager still reports me as connected. Also `sudo iw dev wlp60s0 scan -u` finds my ap without issues. Well.. For now, the quest will continue.